# Assets Upload Error: "Getting content length is not supported."

Tags: assets

When I try to upload a file to Assets, I get this alert:

> Could not upload the file - server returned an unexpected response. Please check the server settings.

The console shows a 500 error when trying to access a url: `https://www.mysite.com/index.php?folder=16&ACT=24&qqfile=my-file.png`

When I load that URL directly in the browser I get this message:

> {"error":"There was an error uploading your file: Getting content length is not supported."}

My server's PHP error logs don't show anything.

- EE 2.7.2
- Assets 2.2.2

Comment: Echo this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8051722/135935. Does it return 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked and saw a pale horse whose rider's name was FastCGI, and all of hell followed him.